# How to implement Bottom Navigation with navigation graph while maintaining tab states?

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation-graph

I have 5 menu item in bottom navigation let's suppose (A,B,C,D,E).
I have defined navigation graph for each of this menu items.

Let's say I am on Tab **B** of bottom navigation and I perform some click  and now it navigate to a action defined in nav graph **B** and it navigates to **B.1**, into the current  tab B. so the current screen is **B.1**

Now if I click on tab **A** of bottom navigation it opens tab **A**.

**What I want to achive ?**

1. Now If I press back button it should go to **B.1**
2. If I click on Tab **B** of bottom navigation it should Show me the earlier opened Screen that is **B.1** (Currently it's creating new Fragment for **B**).

Nav versions tried

nav_version_ktx = "2.4.0-alpha01" and
nav_version_ktx = "2.3.5"